# Remove whitespace in a string for multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where multiple columns can contain a specific regex expression. My regex matches the pattern where I have a variable amount of capital letters followed by a single white space and numbers.

```
import pandas as pd 

pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Z]+\s\d+")
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['Foo ABC 1234', 'Correct Foo BCD1234', 'Still Wrong DEEF 9345'], 
                    'Description':['Nothing special here XYC1235', 'This is a normal description.', 'This contains BDE 234'], 
                    'Numbers':['BCD1234', 'XYC1235', 'DKO 15000']})
```

All I want is to find those matches in all of the defined columns `['Title', 'Description', 'Numbers']` and remove the singular white space such as:

ABC 1234 ---> **ABC1234**

Is there any way I can do this in place?

So far I tried to use `re.findall()` however that just returns a list of the matches and when I try to replace the substrings it doesn't modify the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replace`:

```
df = df.replace(r'([A-Z]+)\s(\d+)', r'\1\2', regex=True)
```

Or, to only replace in specified columns:

```
df[['Title', 'Description', 'Numbers']] = df[['Title', 'Description', 'Numbers']].replace(r'([A-Z]+)\s(\d+)', r'\1\2', regex=True)
```

Here, `([A-Z]+)\s(\d+)` matches and captures one or more capital letters into Group 1 and `(\d+)` will match one or more digits into Group 2, and the whitespace between will be matched, but not captured. The replacement contains two backreferences to the group values captured, so the whitespace in between will be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the groups. It works perfectly now!